# Working with several variables in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to disable a service on remote servers. I know how to do it 1 at a time, but I want a way to give it a list, and have it do them all. Is there a way I can do that within batch?

**Current method**

```
Set /P pinghost=Enter server IP address:: 
sc \\%pinghost% config "LanSafe III PM" start= disabled
timeout /t 2
sc \\%pinghost% stop "LanSafe III PM"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
wmic /node:@"MyComputerList.txt" service where name="apphostsvc" call changestartmode disabled
```

And MyComputerList.txt formatted so either of the following two ways. No `\\`. You can mix and match.

```
ComputerName
127.0.0.1
```

See `wmic /?`, `wmic service /?`, `wmic service get /?`, `wmic service set /?`, `wmic service call /?`, `wmic /node /?`.

The following command will list computer's names in right format. Redirect it to a file. If pasting or typing it change `%%` to `%`.

```
for /f "skip=3 delims=\" %%A in ('net view ^| findstr /v /C:"The command completed successfully"') do Echo %%A
```

Comment: Forgive me, but I am still a bit confused. Can you give me another example of how it should look.

Comment: No. It's sufficient.